# Библиотека AE.Net.Mail; Очень много кушает ОЗУ

Tags: c#, email

Библиотека AE.Net.Mail; Очень много кушает ОЗУ и при исключениях не выдергивается из ОЗУ

```
try{ ImapClient ic = new ImapClient(serv, login, pass, AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true);
ic.Disconnect();}
            catch (Exception e){ }
```

Как сделать выпуск памяти? Работаю в многопотоке порядка 600 потоков в секунду. И сами понимаете что это не дело. Память загружается очень сильно

Comment: Она одна, что ли?

Comment: @SmInc Вопрос был к озу а не к количеству аналогичных библиотек

Comment: А собственное независимое мнение профессионала - это то, чего не замечает ни один заказчик когда оно есть, но за что можно вылететь со славой аж вселенского зла, если его нет.

Comment: Одно слово: `Dispose`.

Comment: Возьмите любой профайлер памяти, и посмотрите,  что именно кушает. И не забудьте,  что каждый поток сам по себе требует пару мегабайт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как `ImapClient` `IDisposable`, то нужно вызывать метод `Dispose()` или использовать `using`.

```
try
{ 
  using(ImapClient ic = new ImapClient(serv, login, pass, AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))
  {
    ic.Disconnect();
  }
}
catch (Exception e){ }
```